# How can I send a File via HTTP POST along with my other text parameters?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv, post, http-post

I've currently setup my method to send some information via HTTP POST and get a response.  I sent the information as a string to the function in the variable `post_info`. (ex:  `"name=" & username & "&pass=" & password`). This works but I don't know how to send a csv file along with it like so... "name=user&pass=password&file=[myfile]".

```
Public Sub MyRequest(ByVal url As String, ByVal post_info As String, Optional SendingFile As Boolean = False)

    Dim req As HttpWebRequest
    Dim enc As UTF8Encoding
    Dim postdata As String
    Dim postdatabytes As Byte()

    req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
    enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    postdata = post_info
    postdatabytes = enc.GetBytes(postdata)
    req.Method = "POST"
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = True
    req.ContentLength = postdatabytes.Length

    Using stream = req.GetRequestStream()
        stream.Write(postdatabytes, 0, postdatabytes.Length)
    End Using

    Using response As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()
        Dim contentLength As Long = response.ContentLength
        Dim bytesReceived As Long = 0.0
        Dim bufferLength As Integer = 8192
        Dim buffer(bufferLength) As Char
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder

        Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Do
                Dim bufferedCount As Integer = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
                sb.Append(buffer, 0, bufferedCount)
                bytesReceived += bufferedCount
                Console.WriteLine(bytesReceived / contentLength * 100 & "%")
            Loop While bytesReceived < contentLength
        End Using

        json_response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sb.ToString)

    End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options (the first is easier, the second one is more elegant):

1. Use HttpUtility.UrlEncode on the CSV file contents and use this value in the request body: `"name=user&pass=password&file=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myfileContents)`
2. Use **Content-Type: multipart/form-data** which was designed for this purposes. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388

Comment: Is there a size limit for #1 option? for instance if my CSV is XXMB will this method still work ?

Comment: It depends on the server and its settings - for example the default limit for POST request size in ASP.NET applications is 4MB. 
However the limits typically apply to all HTTP POST requests and do not differ accross various Content-Type values. 
The second method is better because it was designed to transfer files and it should be much more efficient on the server side because the request body won't be loaded in memory - the files will probably be saved to temporary files.